# BFTask to return when nested query is complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, parse-platform, bolts-framework

I'm performing a query in conjunction with `BFTask` and Parse. Within the task is a nested query. I wish to return the task only when the outer query has finished fetching the necessary data to add to `complete` (including data fetched by the inner query). I have already achieved a solution using the main thread, however I do not want to block the user interface.

```
+ (BFTask*)theTask {      
    BFTask *task = [BFTask taskFromExecutor:[BFExecutor defaultExecutor] withBlock:^id{
        NSMutableArray *complete = [NSMutableArray new]; //do not return complete until it has been populated by relationObj's
        [[QueryLibrary queryA] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            for(PFObject *obj in objects) {
                PFQuery *relationQuery = [obj relationForKey:@"aRelation"].query;

                [relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    for(PFObject *relationObj in objects) {
                        //inspect and possibly augment relationObj...
                        [complete addObject: relationObj];
                    }    
                }];
            }
        }];
        return complete;
    }];

    return task;
}
```

I've tried to restructure my query (`queryA`) to include the relation. When trying to include the relation, I get the following errors:

```
+ (PFQuery *)queryA {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"aPFObjectSubclass"];
    //include other qualifiers...
    [query includeKey:@"aRelation"]; //[Error]: field aRelation cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)
    [query whereKeyExists:@"aRelation"]; // [Error]: Unsupported query operator on relation field: aRelation (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible in your scenario to call `[query includeKey:'aRelation'];` on the first query?

That would make it return the aRelation objects without having to run `relationQuery` in a loop, which would eliminate the problem of doing that on the main thread altogether.

More info: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/queries-for-relational-data/

Comment: Yup, I tried that. When using `[query includeKey:@"aRelation"]` I get the error: `[Error]: field aRelation cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)`. When using `[query whereKeyExists:@"aRelation"]` I get the error: `[Error]: Unsupported query operator on relation field: aRelation (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)`

Comment: Ah, yes - to be able to use `includeKey:`, you need to add the "aRelation" objects using 

`object[@"aRelation"] = @[relationObject1, relationObject2];`

not

`[[object relationForKey:@"aRelation"] addObject:relationObject1]`


Then, instead of the nested query, you will be able to get all objects in the relations using this:


`[[objects valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.aRelation"] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.self"]`


Let me know if this is possible in your scenario, or if avoiding the nested query is impossible after all.

Answer (score 0):

In .h file declare  `typedef void(^ completion)(NSMutableArray *);`

Implementation of your method should look like this:

```
+ (BFTask *)theTask:(completion) completion {
  BFTask *task = [BFTask taskFromExecutor:[BFExecutor defaultExecutor] withBlock:^id{
    NSMutableArray *complete = [NSMutableArray new]; //do not return complete until it has been populated by relationObj's
    [[QueryLibrary queryA] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable topObjects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        for(PFObject *obj in topObjects) {
            PFQuery *relationQuery = [obj relationForKey:@"aRelation"].query;

            [relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                for(PFObject *relationObj in objects) {
                    //inspect and possibly augment relationObj...
                    [complete addObject: relationObj];
                }


                if([topObjects lastObject] == obj) {
                    completion(complete);
                }

            }];
        }
    }];
  }];

  return task;
}
```

Calling your method:

```
[myClass theTask:^(NSMutableArray * complete) {

                //use your "complete" array

}];
```

Comment: Ah.. sorry. I missed that you are looping through the objects

Comment: I considered the option of adding a completion block. This would force a large refactor in other parts of my code. If I were to go that route, I wouldn't use `BFTask` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this would work:

```
+ (BFTask *)theTask 
{      
  BFTask *task = [BFTask taskFromExecutor:[BFExecutor executorWithOperationQueue:[NSOperationQueue defaultQueue]] withBlock:^id {
    NSArray *objectsWithRelations = [[QueryLibrary queryA] findObjects];
    NSMutableArray *subqueries = [NSMutableArray array];            
    for(PFObject *object in objectsWithRelations) {
        [subqueries addObjects:[obj relationForKey:@"aRelation"].query];
    }
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:subqueries];
    NSArray *complete = [query findObjects];
    return complete;
  }];

  return task;
}
```

There is a chance that the `findObject` calls will be synchronous on the thread that the BFTask is dispatched onto, and not dispatched onto the main thread.

In any case, you can reduce the number of `finds` you do by merging the relationship queries into one OR query.

**Update:**

Would this allow you to run only part of the task synchronously then:

```
+ (BFTask *)theTask 
{      
    NSArray *objectsWithRelations = [[QueryLibrary queryA] findObjects];
    NSMutableArray *subqueries = [NSMutableArray array];            
    for(PFObject *object in objectsWithRelations) {
        [subqueries addObjects:[obj relationForKey:@"aRelation"].query];
    }
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:subqueries];
    return [query findObjectsInBackground];
}
```

Comment: FindObjects is always run on the main thread, no matter the context

Comment: @BenJammin if that's the case I see an optimization that might allow running only the first `find` on main... see update above.

Comment: Also, if using a completion block to return the result of your fetches is not an option, have you considered using the delegate pattern, or even NSNotifcation?

Comment: I'm using `BFTask` because it encapsulates this work along with similar functions which are also `BFTask`s. I'm funneling these tasks into another `BFTask` using `BFTask *allTasks = [BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasksWithResults:tasksToWaitFor]`. `TaskToWaitFor` is an array of encapsulated fetches (in `BFTask` objects). I need these to run on a background thread until all the fetches are complete.